# SLDS Grid layout 40-60 ratio

Tags: lightning-design-system

There is a need of designing a layout using SLDS grid system. We have to divide the entire width in 40% - 60% ratio. I am able to divide in 5:7 ratio like below

https://pastebin.com/7TYyBMLa

How can I achieve the 2:3 ratio?

Comment: Slds-size_2-of-5 and 3-of-5 maybes

Comment: @Eric You should add this answer so I can +1 it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SLDS allows grids of [various sizes](https://www.lightningdesignsystem.com/utilities/sizing/). You can use `slds-size_2-of-5` and `slds-size_3-of-5` to get a 2:3 ratio.

Comment: Lol... I figured it out myself, so thought of deleting this question, but then you already gave the answer. Marking the answer as correct.